# How do I connect Netbeans IDE to AWS Bitnami installation?

Tags: 8, deployment

I'm hosting a Drupal 8 installation on AWS using the recommended Bitnami image. I'd like to be able to edit some of the files remotely from my computer using the NetBeans IDE. I've successfully created a NetBeans project and I'm connected remotely to the installation at /opt/bitnami/drupal. However, the project doesn't show key directories there, like /modules, /sites, /profiles or /themes. I can't edit the associated files.

Those directories are all owned by root with permissions 0777.

Has anyone run into this and solved it?

Comment: Not sure what else to say other than read the NetBeans IDE on the remote server / deployment management plugin. Nothing here related to Drupal directly.

Comment: or just install git on the server open edit locally and push to remote